# de + infinitif : facultatif ?

Tags: infinitif, de

Emmanuel Macron a dit, 'La diplomatie, c'est de parler avec des gens avec lesquels on n'est pas d'accord'.

Il y a deux ans, Gérard Araud a dit, 'La diplomatie, c'est parler avec le diable'

Je remarque que seulement le premier dit '**de** parler'.

Ici le **de** c'est facultatif ?

Comment: Effet d'oralité, et surtout de concision et d'intention que les relectures peuvent modifier. — Soit on pense : 'La diplomatie,// [ c'est | == ] parler avec // le diable', définition ‘cinglante/définitive/qui n'attend pas de réponse’ avec une phrase courte, sujet//verbe//complément (qui est plutôt un concept/une idée qu'un objet/une personne) ; — Soit on induit un sous-entendu : 'La diplomatie, c'est [le fait] de parler avec des gens avec lesquels on n'est pas d'accord', phrase plus longue qui explicite la pensée ; le *de* évoque l'existence d'un dialogue.

Comment: Une expression sans *de* : « parler bref » : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parler+bref%2C+de+parler+bref&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3 ; https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=parler+bref%2Cde+parler+bref

Answer (score 1):

Non, je dirais plutôt que cet emploi de "de"  est très inhabituel. On peut attendre "de" lorsque le nom ou verbe se construit avec "de", mais, personnellement, je pense que même  cet usage de "de" n'est pas justifié (parce qu'en fait il ne s'agit que d'une définition) ; cependant, il est assez courant.

- ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Oeuvres_compl%C3%A8tes_de_M_le_Vicomte_de_Ch/Bg6w-uQWH1EC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22c%27est+de+parler%22&pg=PA38&printsec=frontcover)) Je ne lui ferai qu'un reproche, c'est de parler souvent de Wheler
- ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Tueur_de_daims/AVsOCwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22c%27est+de+parler%22&pg=PT85&printsec=frontcover)) Vous n'êtes que de sottes filles, et ce que vous avez de mieux à faire toutes deux, c'est de parler de ce que vous comprenez, et non d'autre chose.
- ([réf](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Journal_des_d%C3%A9bats/3NAqAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22c%27est+de+parler%22&dq=%22c%27est+de+parler%22&printsec=frontcover)) Parce que c'est de ça qu'il s'agit , chers collègues , c'est de parler du principe du projet de loi n ° 85 (*s'agir de*).

Comme il définit la diplomatie, il n'y a aucune raison pour ce "de". Il s'agit probablement d'un lapsus.

Comment: C'est littéraire mais semble assez courant (cf https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de II B. 1.) En tout cas, cet emploi ne me choque pas.

Comment: @guillaume31 « II B. 1. a » dit « en début de phrase avec infinitif sujet » ; ce n'est ni le cas que « de » soit en début de phrase ni le cas que « parler » soit sujet. Il ne s'agit pas de « b  » non plus parce que  « ce », le pronom neutre, n'annonce pas  « parler » mais a pour remplacement « diplomatie » : dans «  C'est bien vrai que ça ne vaut rien pour personne, de vivre les uns sur les autres » le remplacement de « ça » est « vivre ... ». L'usage de « de » dans ce contexte est tellement compliqué que Macron, soumis au contraintes de la langue parlée n'a  (1/3)

Comment: @guillaume31 pas eu le temps d'analyser parfaitement ses mots  ([vidéo](https://twitter.com/franceinter/status/1592058458135674880)). Vu les subtilités qui rendent difficile l'usage de « de » (et le rendent  plus ou moins nécessaire), je ne suis pas surpris par ce qui aurait été, autrement, une erreur bête ; il ne faut pas oublier que Araud se passe de « de »  alors qu'il a tout loisir, par écrit, de choisir ses mots. À ne pas oublier non plus, Macron est capable, lorsque la langue littéraire lui fait défaut, d'utiliser en public des expressions comme « foutre le bordel » ; (2/3)

Comment: @guillaume31 s'il avait été particulièrement soucieux de préserver à son langage un tour littéraire et s'il avait maitrisé la langue littéraire, le jour où il s'est laissé aller à utiliser cette expression vulgaire il aurait probablement choisi autre chose. (3/3)

Comment: Le Président de la République actuel est un homme d'état qui choisit ses mots en fonction du message politique à faire passer au public qui l'écoute, le langage littéraire reste pour l'écrit en ce vingt-et-unième siècle.